# Static Member cannot be used on instance of type error when accessing sub classes

Tags: swift, class, static, nested

I am 100% sure this has been answered but the answers I am finding I cannot seem to make fit into my solution.  I have the following code a playground.

```
import Foundation

public class AuthenticationInfo
{
public class RootObject
{
    var resultParameters: ResultParameters = ResultParameters()

}

public class ResultParameters
{
    var adminInfo: AdminInfo = AdminInfo()
    var ServerBuildNumber: Int = -1
    var ServerIs64Bit: Bool = false
    var ServerOSPlatform: Int = -1
    var ServerStartTime: Int64 = -1
    var ServerVersion: String = ""
    var EnableLiveDataUpdates: Bool = false
    var DelayLiveDataUpdates: String = ""
    var SessionTimeout: Int = 0;
    var ServerName: String = ""
    var ServerPort: Int = -1
    var UserName: String = ""
    var WebAPIVersion: String = ""
    var Locale: String = ""
}

public class AdminInfo
{
    var AdminUUID: String = ""
    var AllowChangeAgentClientInfoSettings: Int = -1
    var AllowChangeAgentCustomFieldSettings: Int = -1
    var AllowChangeAgentGeneralSettings: Int = -1
    var AllowChangeAgentServerSettings: Int = -1
    var AllowChangeComputerTracking: Int = -1
    var AllowChangeComputerTrackingScreenshot: Int = -1
    var AllowChangeCustomFields: Int = -1
    var AllowChangeHistoryOptions: Int = -1
    var AllowChangeMobileDeviceTracking: Int = -1
    var AllowEnterCustomFieldData: Int = -1
    var AllowManageDeviceUsers: Int = -1
    var AllowManageiOSDevices: Int = -1
    var AllowMobileRemoteControl: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyADEPAccount: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyBookstoreBooks: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyMDMDeviceEnrollmentProfiles: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyMobileActions: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyMobileMedia: Int = -1
    var AllowModifySDConfigProfiles: Int = -1
    var AllowModifySDGroups: Int = -1
    var AllowModifySDImages: Int = -1
    var AllowModifySDPackages: Int = -1
    var AllowModifySLPackages: Int = -1
    var AllowModifySamsungLicenses: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyStagingServers: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyVPPAccount: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyiOSApplications: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyiOSConfigurationProfiles: Int = -1
    var AllowModifyiOSPolicies: Int = -1
    var AllowRemoteControl: Int = -1
    var AllowRemoveCommandsFromHistory: Int = -1
    var AllowRemoveComputerRecords: Int = -1
    var AllowRemoveInventoryData: Int = -1
    var AllowRemoveLicenseReports: Int = -1
    var AllowRemoveSDLogEntry: Int = -1
    var AllowRemoveiOSDeviceRecords: Int = -1
    var AllowRemoveiOSHistoryCommands: Int = -1
    var AllowResetSDPackges: Int = -1
    var AllowRetrySDPackges: Int = -1
    var AllowVPPLicenseManagement: Int = -1
    var AllowViewAdminCenter: Int = -1
    var AllowViewCommandsWindow: Int = -1
    var AllowViewComputerTrackingData: Int = -1
    var AllowViewComputerTrackingScreenshot: Int = -1
    var AllowViewCustomFields: Int = -1
    var AllowViewMobileDeviceTrackingData: Int = -1
    var AllowViewSDCenter: Int = -1
    var AllowViewSLCenter: Int = -1
    var AllowViewServerStatus: Int = -1
    var CanChangeServerSettings: Int = -1
    var CanDeployAgents: Int = -1
    var CanLogin: Int = -1
    var CanSeeAllRecords: Int = -1
    var CommandPermissions: Int64 = -1
    var CommandPermissions2: Int = -1
    var IsADUser: Int = -1
    var IsSuperAdmin: Int = -1
    var id: Int = -1
    var CommandPermissionsLow32: Int64 = -1
    var CommandPermissionsHigh32: Int = -1
}

}

var lobj_AuthenticationInfo: AuthenticationInfo
var lobj_AuthenticationInfo_RootObject: AuthenticationInfo.RootObject

lobj_AuthenticationInfo = AuthenticationInfo()
lobj_AuthenticationInfo_RootObject = lobj_AuthenticationInfo.RootObject
```

On the last line I am getting the following error:

Static member RootObject cannot be used on instance of type AuthenticationInfo.

MORE INFO:
These classes were created by a code generator based on JSON data that will be returned from a web api I call.  Thus, I believe the structure of these objects needs to stay intact so when I use EVRefelction to load the data into the class, the structure matches exactly the data.

Can someone please assist me in getting this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Java, in swift, all inner classes are implicitly `static`. For example:

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner {

    }
}
```

When you want to create an object of type `Inner`, you don't need to create an object of type `Outer` first. You can just do this:

```
let x = Outer.Inner()
```

And because inner classes are static, they cannot be accessed with an instance of the outer class:

```
let x = Outer()
let y = x.Inner //Wrong!
```

I think what you want to do here is to have the `RootObject` non-static so that it can be accessed from an instance of `AuthenticationInfo`. This cannot be done directly. You should create an instance of `RootObject` in your `AuthenticationInfo` class:

```
public class AuthenticationInfo {
    public class RootObject {
         //blah blah blah
    }
    // Other inner classes goes here
    var rootObj = RootObject()
}
```

Now you can create an instance of `AuthenticationInfo` and access the `rootObj` stored in the Authentication Info:

```
var x = AuthenticationInfo()
var y = AuthenticationInfo.rootObj
```

From your style of coding, I guess you were a Java programmer. You write all the types of variables explicitly. But in swift, this is seldomly used.

Comment: Should I maybe change the classes to structs?

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr You can. Please note that structs cannot inherit from other types and they are values instead of references. IMO your `ResultInfo` and `AdminParameters` are suitable to become structs.

Comment: So even when I change those two to struct I still get the same error.  These classes were converted from C#.  Is there a different tool that I should use to create my data models in Swift directly from the resulting JSON?  Basically I am want to pass my JSON string to the init method of my AuthenticationInfo class provided by EVReflection and have it create the entire AuthenticationInfo object and allow me to access all the sub objects.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Just do what I said in the answer, add a property of type `RootObject` so that it can be accessed from an instance of `AuthenticationInfo`. I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. Also, this site is not or asking for off-site resources like C# to Swift converters.

Comment: The challenge with your solution is that I believe the EVReflection tool with see the property of type RootObject as an extra property that does not exist in the JSON.  I will try it and see what happens when I de-seriliaze the object.  I did add more info to the question also.  And finally I am not asking for off site resources like c# to swift converters.  i already converted the class.  I was asking if there is a different tool people developing in Swift use to create strongly typed objects for their JSON data that is returned.